# Wireless cuts out abruptly at random times, multiple routers

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I'm having an issue with my wireless, as it appears to enjoy cutting out on me at random times.  Suddenly, I'll be disconnected and sometimes I'll be back on in a minute, other times it decides to not allow me to reconnect (a generic connection failed message) for a minute or two.

Here's the tricky part.

- It does this on my desktop computer, my macbook pro and my roomate's computers.
- It does this on both my wireless router and my friends wireless router.  Mine is a nice Buffalo WHR-HP-G54, my friend's is some weird Zyxel router brand that I've never heard of before.
- It works fine as long as you have a wired connection, so it's not our internet.

There are a bunch of wireless networks in close proximity, but I've tried switching the channel between 1, 6 and 11 and each one seems to fail.  In addition, there's an unsecured wireless access point nearby and it works fine, if a bit laggy.  It was also working fine for months and months, only deciding to mess up within the last week or so.

What else can I try?

EDIT: Even when I'm connected my connection is pretty awful.  If I keep `ping 8.8.8.8 -t` going in the background, it usually gets something reasonable as long as I'm not doing anything, but registers a lot of dropped packets when I load a page with a lot of images or if I visit a site like Superuser for the first time after clearing my cache.  If I try using something like Doomseeker to browse game servers, it grabs about 3/4 of the available IP's and can't seem to refresh all of the servers at once...works fine if I refresh things a server at a time though.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like heavily congested airwaves. Non-802.11b/g devices that use that frequency range can really wreak havoc on wireless transmissions. We had to replace our wireless phone because it caused the wireless to degrade to dial-up speeds when someone was using it, and our older b access-point sometimes dropped completely when someone was using the microwave-oven.

If your WLAN card has these settings, they can be tweaked to perform better in heavily congested environments. I don't have one in front of me, but back in the advanced settings (if any) you can do things like add a preamble to transmissions (which improves interference resistance), as well as the fragmentation threshold.

As a fall-back you might want to consider channels 3 and 9. Yes they overlap, but considering how crowded your airwaves seem to be it's worth a try.

Comment: I have tried all of your suggestions.  I have changed the channel to 9, reduced the preamble from long to short, and changed the fragmentation threshold from 4096 to 2432, as well as another setting called RTS/CTS  Threshold.  While it has not made anything worse and perhaps have made things a little better, we're still getting disconnected at random and lots of activity still causes a backgrounding ping to lose packets.